# Expected number of bets in roulette

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expected-value

I am trying to solve the following question -

> A casino patron will continue to make $5 bets on red in roulette until she has won 4 of these bets. What are her expected winnings when she stops?

This is the solution as given in book-

[image: Solution snapshot]

While I understand the process, I don not understand how $E(X) = 4/(9/19)$.

I started by computing PMF of X, which is as follows :
X will be greater than or equal to 4, and probability of winning is $18/38 = 9/19$ so

$P(X=4) = (9/19)^4$

$P(X=5) = [\binom {4}{3}(9/19)^3(10/19)](9/19)$

$P(X=6) = [\binom {5}{3}(9/19)^3(10/19)^2](9/19)$ and so on

In general, $P(X=k) = [\binom {k-1}{3}(9/19)^3(10/19)^{k-4}](9/19)$

So, $E(X) = \sum_{k=4}^{\infty} k \big[ \binom {k-1}{3}(9/19)^3(10/19)^{k-4}\big](9/19)$

I expanded the series, multiplied it by $10/19$ to get another series and subtracted this from above series i.e., $E(X) - \frac{10}{19}E(X)$ and got the result

$E(X) = \big(\frac{9}{19}\big)^3[4 + \binom{3}{2}\frac{10}{19} + \binom{4}{2}\big(\frac{10}{19}\big)^2 + \binom{5}{2}\big(\frac{10}{19}\big)^3 + ....]$

From here, I am not able to proceed. I know that this is like arithmetico-geometric series, but instead of arithmetic terms, I have *Combination* terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don not understand how E(X)=4/(9/19).

the distribution we need is a Negative Binomial

$$P(X=n)=\binom{n-1}{4-1}\theta^4(1-\theta)^{n-4}$$

$n=4,5,6,\dots$

this distribution has mean $E(X)=4/\theta$

Now there are two types of roulette wheels:

- the French roulette with 36 numbers + 0
- the American roulette with 36 numbers +0+00

if you play on the American roulette, $\theta=\frac{18}{36+2}=\frac{9}{19}$ but if you play on the French one, $\theta=\frac{18}{36+1}=\frac{18}{37}$

[image]

---

Expectation for the NBinomial calculating the needed trials to get 4 successes

$$E(X=x)=\sum_{x=4}^{\infty}x\binom{x-1}{4-1}\theta^4(1-\theta)^{x-4}=$$

$$=\sum_{x=4}^{\infty}\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{3!}\theta^4(1-\theta)^{x-4}=$$

$$=\frac{4}{\theta}\sum_{x=4}^{\infty}\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{4!}\theta^5(1-\theta)^{x-4}=$$

$$=\frac{4}{\theta}\underbrace{\sum_{x+1=5}^{\infty}\binom{(x+1)-1}{5-1}\theta^5(1-\theta)^{(x+1)-5}}_{=1}=\frac{4}{\theta}$$

Comment: Directly using distribution's expected value formula is a nice way but I want to know if there is any way to calculate the series's value. I want to know if that can be done or not.

Comment: Also, negative binomial has various formulations, and each one of then has a different formula for expectation. Can you please point me to the right source where I can get all formulations and their expectations?

Comment: @AnkitSeth : there are 2 types of NBinomial but the one which we are interested in is the one counting the trials to get k successes. I added a full proof for the expectation's calculations. It is just a proof I got thinking at Expectation's definition. Sure if you read some texts you will find other proofs

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the roulette wheel has $38$ slots of which $18$ are red

so the probability of winning a particular spin is $\frac{18}{38} = \frac{9}{19}$

making the expected number of spins to win once $\frac{19}{9}$ (this has a geometric distribution)

and the expected number of spins to win four times $4\times\frac{19}{9}$

Comment: Is this the correct way to proceed - 

probability of winning is $9/19$, so in $19$ spins, she would win $9$ times.

So, $9$ wins in $19$ spins, or $1$ win in $19/9$ spins.